# Grails Ajax tags deprecation

Tags: grails

Does anyone know the reason why so many Ajax related tags are being deprecated from Grails? As far as I can tell, there is no replacement other than providing your own Javascript. They seemed like handy features. I'm just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at below link for AJAX tags deprecation.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/grails-dev-discuss/4yesijtFSB4/PcMs8lF1_mEJ

They will however be moved to a plugin and you should be able to use it.

The main reason for deprecation is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi there. The Google Groups discussions contain some statements like "...will be moved to a plugin". Does anyone know which plugin this is for Grails 3.X? Is there a "cookbook" style guide available for how to migrate existing GSP pages using the linkRemote/formRemote tags? Thanks.